# geth --fast --cache=1024 db corruption?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I started downloading the blockchain from mist wallet, and got frustrated by slow speed after 30%.  I then switched to geth --fast --cache=1024, but did not see until later that I should have used geth removedb beforehand.

geth --fast --cache=1024 is downloading slowly.  Is that the only issue I will have by not using geth --fast --cache=1024 first, or will my db be corrupted for some reason, or any other unknown issues?